# a[0] is undefined, but it is not an array-like-object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
console.log(aData)
```

[image]

But I cant not get the dom form `a[0]` and it is not an array-like-object.

So, how to get the `"div.next-tabs-nav"`?

Comment: Your array is `aData` not `a`. So to get `div.next-tabs-nav` you should use `aData[0]`.

Comment: I think this dom did not be real rended when i console, so it appears as a hidden object.
I can not be lazy, i have change my code and i get it . THX all!